# why when i am printing array content, it gives me wrong output, using awk

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk

I am trying to read the matrix from a file and assign to my matrix declared in bash script,but when i am trying to print the content of the matrix to check that everything is right it gives me a strange output, it seems that `awk` function rewrite my matrix, is there something to say `awk` to append to my matrix not rewrite?

Here is the `.txt` file.

[image]

The Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
function readMatrixFromFile() {
    local file="$1"
    declare -n matrix="$2"
    local num_rows=$(awk 'NR==1 {print $3}' $1)
    local num_colums=$(awk 'NR==2 {print $3}' $1)

    for ((i=3;i<=num_rows+2;i++)) do
    for ((j=1;j<=num_colums;j++)) do

        local k=$(($i-3))
        local l=$(($j-1))

                    matrix[$k,$l]=$(awk -v row=$i -v col=$j 'NR==row {print $col}' $file)       
            done
    done

    for ((i=0;i<num_rows;i++)) do
           for ((j=0;j<num_colums;j++)) do

                   echo ${matrix[$i,$j]}
           done
           echo
    done

}

function Main() {
    declare m
    readMatrixFromFile Matrix3.txt m

}

Main
```

Here is the Output:

[image]

Comment: `declare -n` looks wrong. "The nameref attribute cannot be applied to array variables." Also, I think your array `m` would need to be an associative array (`declare -A`).

Comment: @Mikel yeah you are right, i should array `m` declare as `-A`, but i don't understand about `declare -n`, i declared matrix as `-n` it mean by reference?
Now my program is working correctly, thank you very much, can you share links more about declaring?

Comment: @ilkkachu ok, i will not post images of text :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
matrix[$k,$l]=$(...)
```

This array assignment looks suspicious. I don't think Bash supports proper two-dimensional arrays. Let's see:

```
$ M=()
$ M[0,0]=1
$ M[0,1]=2
$ M[1,0]=3
$ M[1,1]=4
$ declare -p M
declare -a M=([0]="3" [1]="4")
```

Yep, only the last row is present in the array. That's actually because anything before the comma doesn't apply affect the returned value in an arithmetic context:

```
$ echo $(( 123, 456 ))
456
```

The comma is the C-style comma operator: it evaluates both sides and returns the value of the right hand side. Any side effects in the left hand side would still take place. It's [mentioned in Bash's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html) though only with a reference to C in what it does.

---

You might want to use an *associative array* instead, since their keys are strings, and the comma can nicely fit inside the key string:

```
$ unset M
$ declare -A M=()
$ M[0,0]=1
$ M[0,1]=2
$ M[1,0]=3
$ M[1,1]=4
$ declare -p M
declare -A M=([1,1]="4" [1,0]="3" [0,0]="1" [0,1]="2" )
```

You were using that array through a nameref; I think in that case you have to make the array associative before using it that way, so:

```
function Main() {
    declare -A m
    readMatrixFromFile Matrix3.txt m
}
```

---

That said, there's probably some easier way to read an array in than launching `awk` for each element:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -f           # disable globbing
i=0
declare -A M=()
while IFS= read -r line; do
    j=0
    for x in $line ; do     # unquoted $line to get word-splitting!
        M[$i,$j]=$x
        j=$((j+1))
    done
    i=$((i+1))
done << EOF      # replace this with a redirection from the input file
1 2 
3 4  
EOF

declare -p M
```